# SQL to get different values into 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table structure:

```
VEH_GRP VEH_CODE_IND    CATEGORY    DATE    Mileage_1   Mileage_2
1       A               CAR         31-May-08   10  
1       B               CAR         31-May-08           100
```

How can I use a sql query to combine them into 1 row? Ideally I would want to perform computation to divide Mileage_1 over Mileage_2..

Thanks everyone.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: How do you know that this row can be combined?  Is it based on `VEH_GRP`? What happens if there are three rows?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a self join to combine two rows based on some criteria like which 2 rows you require to be combined.
Example :

```
select 
  t1.*,t2.* ,t1.mileage_1/t2.mileage_2
from 
  data_table t1 
inner join 
  data_table t2
on 
  t1.veh_grp = t2.veh_grp
```

Also, you'll need to think of some logic to select which row should represent t1 and which should represent t2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.  I'm not quite sure what the results would look like but:

```
select VEH_GRP, CATEGORY, DATE,
       SUM(Mileage_1), SUM(Mileage_2),
       SUM(Mileage_1) / SUM(Mileage_2)
from t
group by VEH_GRP, CATEGORY, DATE;
```